# how to save a variable and export it in bash

Tags: bash

What I want to do is in order not to hardcode a variable as a string I want to make it a little bit more dynamic.

I want to do something like this:

```
 export SERVER_IP=45.100.1.100 #this works but it is hardcoding

IP = short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com #grabs IP and should save it into a variable
export SERVER_IP = IP #exports IP to an environmental variable
```

How to make this actually work? Thanks.

Comment: No spaces around the `=` : `IP=`.   In the `export`you have a `$` missing (quote for safety):  `export SERVER_IP="$IP"`

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you meant to use is `dig` (presumably):

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

Now, to save the command's STDOUT in a variable, you need command substitution, `$()`:

```
ip=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)
```

Also there must not be any whitespace around `=` in variable declaration in `bash`.

As a side note, don't use all uppercase for variable name in `bash` to prevent accidental overtiring of any environment variable with the same name.

Comment: So I do something like: export server_ip=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)  but then I try to run it I still get:
root@vvv:/srv/www/deploy# server_ip
server_ip: command not found

Comment: @funguy variable is not a command, you can expand it to the value only. Hint: `echo "$server_ip"`